# problem while updating object using jpa

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

I am getting following error while trying to persist object using jpa.AM getting following error

```
NestedThrowables:
<openjpa-1.2.2-SNAPSHOT-r422266:778978M-OPENJPA-975 nonfatal store error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.OptimisticLockException: An optimistic lock violation was detected when flushing object instance "org.apache.openjpa.enhance.com$ibm$cloud$bss$client$db$data$Offeringattribute$pcsubclass-com.ibm.cloud.bss.client.db.data.Offeringattribute-10013800" to the data store.  This indicates that the object was concurrently modified in another transaction.
```

Now i had solved this error last time by inserting some flush statement as shown below

```
em.persist(xyz);
em.flush(); //added this line
dbAttr.setOid((xyz.getId());
em.merge((xyz);
```

But i am not remembering if i did something else last time.Am getting this error even after adding this flush statement.

Note: am running my application as standalong console app and am sure that only 1 thread is running

Comment: In openJPA i never managed to do 2 operations on the same entity. Try <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE"/>

Answer (score 1):

You are running with subclassing enabled and there are a number of known issues with it. First, start off by reading this page about [enhancing your entities](http://openjpa.apache.org/entity-enhancement.html). It shouldn't take more than than a few minutes and in the long run you'll be a much happier camper. The net of that link is that you need to set the following property and use another method of enhancement.

```
<openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses=unsupported/>
```

If this doesn't get you going, you'll need to post your Entity for more clues as to what is going on.

-Rick

Answer (score 0):

An optimistic locking exception happens if you try to update a record which was updated by someone/thing else since you loaded it. This does not require multiple threads to happen.

You should be able to resolve the issue be reloading the entity just before modifying and saving it.

---- update to answer the question ---

The secure way to do it would be to close the Session and use load or get, and make sure you don't change the version attribute (assuming you have such a thing)

Often this is not what you want to do, and if you work only with on thread you entity in the session should be current. So maybe just making sure you don't change the version when merging is enough: load or get the entity from the session, store the version in a variable, perform a merge, reset the version and flush/commit might work.

If it doesn't I need more information, about what you are actually doing.